# The environment files in .production.env is not being picked up when running `docker compose --env-file ./production.env up`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

## what I am trying to do

I tried to build my project on docker using the command:
`docker compose --env-file ./production.env up --build`. I want to define the environment variables in a separate file outside Dockerfile. I used the --env-file flag (https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file).

After executing the command, Docker did not complain and managed to create the container. However, **my project detects that the environment variables are missing** and exits.

## My setup

I am running a node project.
My file structure is

- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- production.env
- ...other files (src folder, etc)

My Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:16-alpine as development

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY package*.json .

    RUN npm install

    COPY . .

    RUN npm run build

    FROM node:16-alpine as production

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY package*.json .

    RUN npm ci --only=production

    COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

    CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3.4"

    services:
      api:
        build:
          context: .
          target: production

        ports:
          - 8888:8888
```

My node project requires environment variables to run and will throw and exception if not all env variables are detected. These env vars are stored in production.env file and a sample of how my production.env file looks:

```
    DB_URI=https://urihere.net
    PASSWORD_KEY=somepw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually passing the environment variables on to the container.

One option is to use Compose [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) to pass the entire file of environment variables to the container; you would not need a `docker-compose --env-file` option in this case.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    env_file:
      - production.env
```

```bash
docker-compose up --build -d  # no --env-file
```

A second is to keep the `--env-file` option, but to use an [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) option to pass along each of the values to the container.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    environment:
      - DB_URI        # without an `=value` part
      - PASSWORD_KEY
```

```bash
docker-compose --env-file production.env up -d --build
```

Compose has two layers of environment variables.  The normal Unix environment, the `.env` file, and any `--env-file` files get used to create a set of variables that can be used for variable substitution in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  However, these are not automatically passed on to individual containers' environments; only the `environment:` and `env_file:` contents are used (augmenting and overriding the images' `ENV` lines).

Comment: Thank you good sir. The first one worked! I cannot believe I did not try that.